# Preventing Emacs from Converting Tabs to Spaces

Tags: emacs, tabs, converters, space

Is there a way to prevent Emacs from converting tabs to spaces by default upon buffer save?

Comment: Emacs doesn't do that. What mode do you use?

Comment: What's the value of `before-save-hook`?  (You can check with `C-h v`.)

Comment: I'd guess you've got a call to `untabify` in one of your hooks (perhaps `write-file-hooks` or `before-save-hook`) and possibly have set `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` (although strictly speaking, the latter would only affect the tabs *you* insert).  See these wiki entries on [untabifying](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UntabifyUponSave) and [no tabs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs).

Comment: Strange, my `write-file-functions` contain `(undo-tree-save-history-hook)` and `before-save-hook` contain `(delete-trailing-whitespace c-auto-insert-pragma-once)`. `untabify` is not called upon save. Hmm maybe my `svn` settings are to blame...